# How can I configure Entity Framework Core to handle nchar(N) fields retrieved from Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, entity-framework-core, migration, nchar

We have done a migration from Microsoft SQL Server to Oracle. We use Entity Framework Core code-first.

We have some columns in the databases of type `nchar(n)`, and as you already know, if we insert 'ismail' into a `NCHAR(10)` column, it will be inserted as `'ismail    '`.

When we point the connection string to SQL Server and we search for a record by its Id, it's found and retrieved and works fine. But when we connect to Oracle, it returns null because I need to add spaces to the Id.

I tried this in my entity model. But this didn't worked.

```
entity.Property(e => e.Name)
      .HasConversion(new ValueConverter<string, string>(v => v.TrimEnd(), v => 
       v.TrimEnd()));
```

Comment: So why aren't you using `NVARCHAR2(n)` datatypes in Oracle, to avoid this hassle?

Comment: @marc_s because it will impact the production's code